# How to use Mocha assertions inside Puppeteer page.on events? UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to run assertions inside Puppeteer's `page.on('response')` event, however, the following error is thrown and the test wrongly passes: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError`.

I've read that returning a promise should do the trick, but how can I resolve the promise if I don't know when the event will stop being emitted?

Here is the complete example code:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const config = require('../config.json');

describe('Tests', function () {
    let browser;
    let page;

    this.timeout(30000);

    before(async function () {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: config.headless
        });
        page = await browser.newPage();
    });

    after(async function () {
        await browser.close();
    });

    it('No responses with blacklisted URLs', async function () {
        const blacklistedUrls = ['tia', 'example'];

        page.on('response', response => {
            blacklistedUrls.forEach(blacklistedUrl => {
                const contains = response.url().includes(blacklistedUrl);
                assert.equal(contains, false);
            });
        });

        await page.goto('http://google.com/');
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you check my answer? Please let me know if it hasn't worked for you so I can re-review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an array at the outer scope of `page.on` to fill with black-listed URLs and then wait for `page.goto` to finish page loading using [`page.goto`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) `waitUntil` options and assert the array length at the end of the page load. You can even use that array to print the blacklisted URLs at the assertion message.

<sup>*Please read inline comments*</sup>

```js
it('No responses with blacklisted URLs', async function () {
    const blacklistedUrls = ['tia', 'example'];

    // Have an array to keep each blacklisted URLs
    const blacklistedUrlsFound = [];

    page.on('response', response => {
        // Use some instead forEach to evaluate the rule, it will be faster
        const hasBlacklistedUrls = blacklistedUrls.some(url => response.url().indexOf(url) >= 0);

        // If response url has blacklisted urls add the url to the array
        if (hasBlacklistedUrls) {
            blacklistedUrlsFound.push(response.url());
        }
    });

    // Visit tha page and wait for network to be idle (finish requesting external urls)
    await page.goto('http://google.com/', { waitUntil: ["networkidle0"] });

    // Finally assert using the blacklistedUrlsFound.length and print the black-listed urls
    assert.equal(blacklistedUrlsFound.length > 0, false,
        `There are black-listed URLs:\n${blacklistedUrlsFound.map(url => `\t${url}`).join('\n')}`);
});
```

You'll get your test working without any exception errors and of course it will fail because there are response URLs containing `tia` at least:

[image: Puppeteer Mocha assert test]